# Form of initial conditions to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can an ODE of the form (i.e. second order ODE):
$$ x''= \ x$$

only have initial values of the form:
$$x(0)=A \ \ \ ,\ \ \ x'(0)=B $$

I mean, can we have an initial condition like $ \ \  x(0)=A \ \ \ ,\ \ \ x''(0)=B $ , i.e., involving a second order initial condition?

Comment: You could but not at the same value of $x$ since $x''=x$. Try with $x(0)=A$, $x''(1)=B$. It works.

Comment: You are very welcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution of $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=x(t)$ can be expressed on the form :
$$x(t)=c_1\cosh(t)+c_2\sinh(t)$$
The condition $x(0)=A$ implies $A=c_1$

The condition $x''(0)=B$ implies $B=c_1$

As a consequence, if $A\neq B$ there is no solution because $c_1$ cannot be simultaneously equal to two different numbers.

If $A=B$, there are an infinity of solutions with $c_1=A=B$ and any value $c_2$
$$x(t)=A\cosh(t)+c_2\sinh(t)$$